# What is the problem with this foreach loop?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

why doesnt this array work? What do I do wrong? The result of my foreach loop is always either empty or just some weird numbers and signs. So what is wrong with my foreach loop?

```
$array = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    if(!empty($row["some"])) {
        $array["some"] = $row["some"];
        $array["some2"] = $row["some2"];
    }

}
foreach($array as $property=>$value) {
echo '<p>'.$value["some"].' - '.$value["some2"].'</p>'; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$array["some"]` and `$array["some2"]` are specific array elements. You are overwriting them every iteration of your while loop.

Not sure what you're trying to actually accomplish but I think possibly this is what you want:

```
$array = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    if(!empty($row["some"])) {
        $array["some"][] = $row["some"];
        $array["some2"][] = $row["some2"];
    }

}
foreach($array["some"] as $property=>$value) {
  echo '<p>'.$value.' - '.$array["some2"][$property].'</p>'; 
}
```

or

```
$array = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    if(!empty($row["some"])) {
        $array[] = array('some' => $row["some"],
                         'some2' => $row["some2"]);
    }

}
foreach($array as $property=>$value) {
  echo '<p>'.$value['some'].' - '.$value['some2'].'</p>'; 
}
```

or similar...kinda depends on what you're ultimately trying to accomplish...

Comment: You are right! I totally didnt see that. So the right version would be $array[]["some"] = $row["some"]; wouldnt it be?

Answer (score 2):

$array will have only two properties, `some` and `some2`. Therefore your foreach loop doesn't make any sense. The foreach will loop two times, the first time with this:

```
$property = 'some';
$value = $row["some"];
```

and the second with this:

```
$property = 'some2';
$value = $row["some2"];
```

You will have to make $array multidimensional in your first loop by doing this:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $new = array();
    if(!empty($row["some"])) {
        $new["some"] = $row["some"];
        $new["some2"] = $row["some2"];
        $array[] = $new;
    }
}
```

or shorter:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    if(!empty($row["some"])) {
        $array[] = array('some' => $row["some"],
                         'some2' => $row["some2"]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't explain the weird numbers and signs, but you are overwriting `$array['some'] and $array['some2']` on each loop iteration.

Instead, try this:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    if(!empty($row["some"])) {
        $array[] = array("some"=>$row['some'], "some2"=>$row['some2']);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$array[] = array('some' => $row["some"], 'some2' => $row["some2"]);
```

But it would be better to retrieve only these columns.

Answer (score 0):

Emil has the right answer :D. I love how people post so fast on here lol.